# Accessing a registry entry for a server IP

Tags: c#

Is there a way to get a registry value from a server IP in c#?

I know to get for a local machine

Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Test"))

Instead of local machine, i need to find out for a server IP, in other words i need to access registry entry of test folder under software residing in a server.

Yours thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to open a key from a remote machine, check out [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zha3xws%28VS.71%29.aspx). It basically involves the following:

1. Setting `RegistryPermissionAttribute` and `SecurityPermissionAttribute` for security purposes.
2. Using `RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey` to connect to a remote key.

HTH